# onUpdate in model definition of sequelize not working

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

onUpdate key in model definition for a column doesn't update the column value when updated

Sequelize Version : 4.41.2
Node Version : 8.15.0

I have a table `test`as described below:

```
+--------------+--------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                           | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | bigint(20)                     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| is_active    | tinyint(1)                     | YES  |     | 1       |                |
| created_at   | datetime                       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at   | datetime                       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and this is its model definition in my code:

```
sequelize.define("test", {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    is_active: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    created_at: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
      allowNull: false,
      get: function() {
        return new Date(this.getDataValue('created_at')).valueOf();
      }
    },
    updated_at: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
      onUpdate : Sequelize.NOW,
      allowNull: false,
      get: function() {
        return new Date(this.getDataValue('updated_at')).valueOf();
      }
    }
  });
```

When I try to update any column such as `is_active` the `updated_at` field value doesn't change in the database even when `onUpdate` is mentioned.

Ideally it should update, but it doesn't.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge onUpdate is solely for directing Sequelize what to do for associations. I think you need to read the docs for timestamps, paying special attention to the last line in that section: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-definition.html#timestamps

Comment: @ChrisWhite but what about when updating some field, i want the updated_at to be changed
If i use
```
timestamp: true,
createdAt: "created_at",
updatedAt: "updated_at"
```
then it always updates the updated_at field even when there is no change in other field values